# Ready to be working for lower salary for less responsibilities

Tags: software-industry, corporate-responsibility

I joined this company two years back. I easily get used to new environments/new language with in few days, other people in company are working on same thing like java coding then they handle only java projects and they are never assigned any unusual tasks.

My company has been paying me heavily with large bonus+big salary due to extra skills, they started bringing in different projects on other technologies and I easily got used to them.

Now its time that after 2 years I realize that money is not everything and I would like to work as others work and I am ready even if they reduce my salary for that, so that I am treated like other normal employees.

I don't know how to face this situation, how to convey this thing, I think they will not let me leave the job or this position without a broken heart and keep on giving more big offers and offers and I don't want to do that and turn this situation into a fight as I respect them a lot for giving so much exposure in past.

Has anybody had similar experience I want to work in same company on a lower scale, what is the best way to convey this.

Edit:

I am not the only one doing research work, there are 3 others too who are getting good package for same.

Edit 2:
Treated Like other Employees means the one with lower salary but easier projects, although working hour's are same.

Comment: Dont thing the tag is correct.

Comment: So you are the only person doing this in your company?

Comment: so in fact your employer has been so dumb to make one person responsible for delivering on a large part of new business.. They must have never heard of the "bus" drama ;)

Comment: @legomaker nopes , there may be more than million, but in my company they are only 3-4 which get paid much more than normal.

Comment: Why can't you ask to be switched to other projects? Is there something you know about your company and/or manager that makes asking for things difficult?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would personally approach this as trying to have my cake and eat it, too.  I would at least try.  Is the problem the time involved in your projects, or the skill required?

If it's the time, that's much easier.  Don't say "I want the same workload as the average worker bee".  Just explain that you need more time, and don't mind if you get less pay.  Generally a bonus is awarded for going above and beyond the standard.  Try to sacrifice some of your bonus for a smaller workload.  It's probably better to stay above the status quo, but as you stated, money isn't everything.

I have a friend that's not in software, but he was in a similar position.  He was basically the only guy in his company that could do his job.  They paid him dearly for it, but it crushed his soul.  He asked to hire someone to help him, and he got it.  He asked for more time off, and he got it.  He stopped wearing suits, and they said nothing.

You're in a pretty good position here if your company is making money.  I highly suggest before jumping off of the deep end to try and work the system to find a middle ground where you can be happy.

Comment: thank you very much,  much appreciated and thanks for the example of your friend :)